# Why can't I select Suspend as on-lid-closed action for AC?

Tags: 14.04, laptop, suspend, power-management

When I go to "Power" and try to select "suspend" when laptop lid closed, on AC power, I find that suspend is greyed out, disabled.

I don't understand why. Suspend works fine when on battery.

I'm using Gnome Shell on 14.04.

[image: screenshot]